# How to handle Behat Mink HTTP basic authentication

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

I am working in Firefox, via the Behat Mink framework's bridge to the Selenium 2 driver. When I run the test, I get an HTTP proxy authentication popup. My **behat.yaml** file has a basic authentication username and password but they don't work. Could you please give me an idea to handle this popup authentication?

[image]

I also tried with the setBasicAuth() function, but it did not work for me:

```
$this->getSession()->getDriver()->setBasicAuth('dharmalingam' ,'Welcome123');
```

My behat.yml contains:

```
extensions:
      Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
        default_session: selenium2
        javascript_session: selenium2
        goutte:              ~
        selenium2:
          browser: 'firefox'
          wd_host: http://dharmainin:6eb372e8-708f-4e07-a33f-b712aab3cd77@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub
          capabilities:
              version: ~
              platform: 'Windows 2008'
      features/extensions/SauceIntegration.php:
        param1: value1
    context:
        parameters:
          base_url: "http://example.com/"
          basic_auth:
            username: 'dharmalingam'
            password: 'Welcome123'
```

Comment: Hi All I belive  there is no native support for this scenarios

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you being prompted for authentication details for an HTTP proxy, or the site itself?  If the site itself, you should be able to embed the username and password into the URL itself, using the `username:password@domain` standard. The following should work in your behat.yml file:

```
base_url: http://dharmalingam:Welcome123@xxxx.com/
```

(Similar to the authentication details embedded into the saucelabs URL in the snippet above.)

Comment: Yes, You are right. It's working :) Site was prompted for authentication details for an HTTP proxy. It is working by adding Username and Password into the URL

Comment: What if your page opens an iframe which requires basic auth? Then setting auth through base_url doesn't work. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

You can handle authentication part by Sikuli, Selenium integration. Here is [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sikuli/0.3.0/frames)